# What variables determine the pitches produced by a flute and its intonation?

Tags: acoustics

I recently read about and heard recordings of the bansuri, a bamboo flute used in Indian (Hindu) music. I decided to try and make one myself, and according to the tutorial I read it shouldn't be too difficult, but there are some points I need to get clear about:

The tutorial said to find a bamboo stalk with an internal diameter of between 3/4" to 7/8", according to the scale you want the flute to be tuned to. So I figure both the length AND the internal diameter of the pipe determine the base pitch it produces, yes? If that's the case, because you can't have very specific sizes when picking a random bamboo, am I required to make specific calculations against the measured internal diameter in order to find the exact length the bamboo should be cut to if I want to reach a specific concert pitch (A, for example)?

And then there's the question about intonation (accuracy of all pitches along a scale): if the internal diameter of the bamboo stalk is not consistent along its entire length, will the pitches be off-scale if I were to make the finger holes positioned without correction as dictated by simple perfect-scenario (symmetrical bamboo) calculations? If it is so, should I rather find a bamboo stalk with a smaller internal diameter and sand it on the inside to a specific, symmetrical diameter?

And the final question — is there a way to make such a simple instrument chromatic rather than just major-scale? It seems like flutes don't use an excessive amount of finger holes for this (if that could even reach the desired result) but rather use keys that allow for secondary in-between notes, so I figure.

Answer (score 1):

The vibration of an object (either the air inside the flute, a string, or a membrane) is formed by the superposition of various "normal modes" of vibration, each with a different frequency. The lowest frequency is typically obtained when the whole object moves in the same direction; e.g. a string makes an arc, not an S-shaped curve. This frequency is the "fundamental". In 1-dimensional objects, such as a string, the higher frequencies are typically multiples of the fundamental: they are called the "armonics". Such sounds are the "notes". 2- or 3-dimensional objects generate more complex superpositions of frequencies, that we hear as "noise": an example is the drum. This does not mean that a "noise" is not nice, nor that it does not have a specific pitch and cannot be evaluated as a note.

A flute generates a "note", so it should be 1-dimensional. This is almost true, since its vibration is mostly along the length. If the diameter is small compared to the length, what determines the sound is basically the length; the diameter and the possible variation of diameter only determine the harmonics, and hence the particular "voice" of the instrument. However, if the diameter is large, you start hearing a "noise", corresponding to transversal vibrations. It is, e.g., the particular sound similar to the wind that you hear in the Pan flute. If the diameter is very large, you get a real "noise", such as in the didjeridoo: although it is a noise, it can be nice!

So, summarizing: the diameter does not define the frequency; what matters is only the length. Also if there are variation in internal diameter, the "keys" must not be displaced. However, the particular "voice" that you will get depends on such details.

Finally, this is what physics teaches us. The experts in music can teach you much more.

Comment: I play guitar (and a bit of other instruments) and read about *harmonics/overtones (which are basically involved in the timbre of a note), but I don't really understand your definitions involving "1/2/3 dimensional" objects. In what way are strings or a flute 1 dimensional? And if the width of the pipe doesn't matter I suppose it makes the manufacture of a playable flute much easier than I suspected, but I would still like to know what should one do to make a flute chromatic (that is, play all 12 semitones in the Western octave)?

Comment: @TLSO It is explained in the answer. If the flute's diameter is small compared to it's diameter, then we really only need to focus on vibrations along the *length* (1D). The exact value diameter shouldn't matter in this regime.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens I suppose you wanted to say "compared to its *length", but either way even if you define the parameters involved in the fundamental pitch production as "dimensions", and in a flute you say it's one dimensional because only (to an extent) the pipe's length is involved, the string of a stringed instrument on the other hand is also affected by its diameter and tension. I'm still trying to understand how can I also turn a simple flute into a chromatic-capable flute; what additional modifications to the embouchure + finger holes construction could be done to add all possible tones?

Comment: @TLSO yes sorry for that typo. For the guitar the vibrations only propagate in one dimension (along the length of the string). We don't consider vibrations along the string's thickness. Tension isn't a dimension.

Comment: @TLSO in other words. For the guitar string you can express the wave amplitude as a function of just one spatial dimension and time.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens OK, so the propagation is only in the direction of the string's length (probably not exactly either), but the string's thickness (and tension) does affect the resulting frequency, as a string of a specific length and tension would produce lower notes with larger diameters, or lower notes with the same length and diameter but lower tension. So I'm trying to understand how does the physical aspect of the "1 dimensionality" of the flute, whose frequency is supposedly only affected by its length, correlates with that of the string.

Comment: @TLSO The string's thickness and tension modifies the wave speed, and hence the fundamental frequencies. The flute's diameter doesn't modify the fundamental frequencies (in the small diameter limit).

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Perhaps we're getting a little off-topic here, but I'm trying to figure why does adding more material (or volume) to a string changes the frequency in a string-sourced note while "adding more material" (more air) in an air-sourced note doesn't. Though now I'm also interested in whether air density should affect the notes produced by a flute; helium makes the timbre of your voice higher than usual because it's less dense than air. So does playing at higher altitudes (or in hotter weather, I suppose) cause the notes to be more treble-y with weaker bass frequencies?

Comment: @TLSO *I'm trying to figure why does adding more material (or volume) to a string changes the frequency in a string-sourced note while "adding more material" (more air) in an air-sourced note doesn't.* See my previous comment. A larger diameter flute doesn't change the density of air. Yes, different density fluid would change things.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens I didn't say it changes the density, but that there is more air mass across a larger volume. The density of a thicker string isn't really changed either. And as far as I understand, when you speak after inhaling helium, you don't really change the fundamentals of your speech, but the timbre is changed due to different harmonic response of the lighter gas.

Comment: @TLSO An example of a 2-dimensional sting is a membrane, such as on a drum. A larger volume of air of the same density and pressure in a pipe corresponds to a larger number of strings, which are all the same and vibrate at the same frequency. Often instruments (e.g. a saxophone) can be fine tuned by moving the mouth piece. In any case, intonations on any tempered instrument are a tough business. Good luck!

Comment: @TLSO The velocity on a string is given by $$v=\sqrt{\frac T\lambda}$$ where $T$ is the tension and $\lambda$ is the linear mass density. The velocity of sound in a fluid is given by $$v=\sqrt{\frac\beta\rho}$$ where $\beta$ is the bulk modulus and $\rho$ is the volume mass density.

Comment: I answer the first question, about 1/2/3 dimensions. Of course, every object is 3-d. But now consider a vibrating string. The "vibration" that you see is a transversal vibration of the whole string. It has a fundamental frequency plus harmonics. Of course, the string also has other vibrations, such as propagation of sound along the diameter, but such modes of vibration have much higher frequency and we do not hear them. The flute is intermediate: the vibrations along the diameter can be heared, if the diameter is very large. In any case, the diameter and the section affect the harmonics.

Comment: @safesphere OK, I think I understand more-or-less. I'm still trying to understand what construction is used on flutes which allow for chromatic notes. From a video I watched (but only called the key function "Bb thumb key) it seems the keys are basically thumb-pressed "buttons" to the side of the instrument which help achieving finger-hole closures that would otherwise be awkward to perform if you weren't able to make use of your thumbs? Am I correct? And thus the chromatics are actually represented by actual finger holes on the top-side of the flute?

Comment: I don't know much specifically about the flute, but I believe all chromatic notes are there; some of them may be played with more than one hole closed; there may be supplemental hole(s) that don't represent specific notes, but change the pitch of the notes played. You just need to find soecific information on the flute design somewhere (not on this site). Alternatively you could create your own design, say, with a hole per chromatic note straight forward. However it would require a different technique for playing compared to a standard instrument. Also note that the alto flute is transposed.